# Expected String or Buffer Error

Tags: python

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong with this block of code. It is for reading line starting with 'READ' on a csv file. The error I am getting is 
return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

```
import csv
import re
f1 = open("1.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f1)
header = reader.next()
f2 = open("out.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(f2)
writer.writerow(header)
for row in reader:
if re.match(r'^.*READ $', row):
writer.writerow(row)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indent your code number 1...

This may work...

```
import csv
import re

f1 = open("1.csv", "rb")
reader = csv.reader(f1)
header = reader.next()
f2 = open("out.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(f2)

writer.writerow(header)
for row in reader:
    if re.match(r'^.*READ $', str(row)):
        writer.writerow(row)

f1.close()
f2.close()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You so much. It solved the error. What I am trying to do is to read a CSV  file that is 1.csv and write selective rows from that file into another csv file that is out.csv. Rows which I want to filter out are those whose column I starts with READ and whose column K is not equal to 0000.These two conditions need to be met. I want to ignore all other rows as there are 12000 rows in my 1.csv which is the input.Is it correct way of doing it ? What I am getting after executing this code is I created a new file out.csv with just the header. There is no other information in my out.csv file